# Best Practice in Defining Multiple Seasonal Components in TBATS

Tags: r, time-series, frequency, timeserieschart

I'm trying to decompose a multiseasonal time series. I have 11 years of data taken at a daily interval, with leap days included for the leap years which occurred from 2006 to 2016, inclusive. The time series is actually a 'difference series'. More specifically, I have two sinusoidal datasets that measure Arctic sea-ice extent and are perfectly in phase, but the two datasets are derived differently. Therefore, I have taken dataset1 - dataset2 to produce the difference series. Within the difference series, there is some seasonality. There are times of year when dataset1 has more ice than dataset 2, and vice versa.

Here is what the difference series looks like plotted as an R 'XTS object' after NANs have been interpolated with na.approx():

*XTS object of my sea ice extent difference series*
[image]

If I were to lay each year on top of one another, the difference series looks like so:

*Seasonal Biases in Difference Series*
[image]

After a Fourier analysis, I know that there are three large spikes in the power spectrum at 335 days, 175 days, and 118 days. I would like to see if it's possible to decompose these data in TBATS, so I have created an 'msts' time series as:

```
Diff_msts <- msts(Diff_series, start = c(2006,01,01), end = c(2016,31,12), seasonal.periods = c(335,175,118))
```

However, I'm not sure if it makes sense to feed this in TBATS, or how to plot the resulting components. Here's what I have tried:

```
Diff_msts.fit <- tbats(Diff_msts)
plot(Diff_msts.fit)
```

I expected to see something like Figure 3 in De Livera, Hyndman, and Snyder 2010: "Forecasting time series with complex seasonal patterns using exponential smoothing"

But I am only getting 'observed' and 'level' as my plot results which look identical (I would post here, but I need a higher reputation to do so). I'm too new to this field of stats to test whether or not my time series would work with tbats.

Any help or recommendations would be wonderful. Thank you.

Small update (09/26/17): When I changed the seasonal.periods = c() to include 365.25 in the vector, I am now getting different seasonal components in the plot! However, I'm unsure why this is the case? Why does setting the vector to 'c(335, 175, 118)' cause the TBATS function to get caught up?

Also, does the order of the seasonality matter? For instance, the Fourier Analysis revealed that the largest peak in the power spectrum occurs at 175 days. Should c(season1, season2,...) be populated in order of strongest to weakest signal: c(175, 335, 118)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! please edit your question to include the updated info, rather than commenting. In general that makes it easier to answer, and it also bumps your question to the top of the new queue again!

Comment: @ConradParker, will do. Thank you!